# D3.js highlight related nodes / links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Question:** I want to fade / highlight a whole dependency chain, based on the link type.

To do so I utilize the mouseEnter event, which currently store all links and nodes. Further I fade  all nodes and links and only highlight those nodes which where filtered as related nodes and links. It would require to check all related nodes and links again, if those have connections from type `need` too. This must be done as long as dependency connections are found.. I can´t figure out a proper algorythm.

**Examples:**

For better understanding I created a beer ingredients dependency, which looks lika a star. For those purposes my version is fine. **BUT** the second chain, about car -> wheel -> tires -> rubber and the radio is giving me headache. The radio is a "`use`" dependency, means its not mandatory for the chain and shouldn´t be hightlighted.

**Expected result:**

If the cursor is over `car` all connected nodes with a "need" dependency should be highlighted and the rest should fade.

For those who wants to help me with, please dont hesitate to ask, if anything is unclear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background: #e6e7ee;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .faded {
        opacity: 0.1;
        transition: 0.3s opacity;
    }

    .highlight {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <svg id="svg"></svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "beer",
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "water",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "hop",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "malt",
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "yeast",
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "car",
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "wheels",
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "tires",
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": "rubber",
                },
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "name": "radio",
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 1,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 2,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 3,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 4,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 10,
                    "target": 11,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 11,
                    "target": 12,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 12,
                    "target": 13,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 10,
                    "target": 14,
                    "type": "use"
                }

            ]
        }

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
            .attr("height", window.innerHeight)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // append markers to svg
        svg.append("defs").append("marker")
            .attr("id", "arrowhead")
            .attr("viewBox", "-0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 8)
            .attr("refY", 0)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .attr("markerWidth", 50)
            .attr("markerHeight", 50)
            .attr("xoverflow", "visible")
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", "M 0,-1 L 2 ,0 L 0,1")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .style("stroke", "none")

        var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", linksContainer)
        var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", nodesContainer)

        var force = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id
            }).distance(80))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2))
            .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(90))

        initialize()

        function initialize() {

            link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
                .style("display", "block")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", 1)

            linkPaths = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("path")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("class", "linkPath")
                .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
                .attr("stroke-opacity", 1)
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkPath" + i })
                .style("display", "block")

            linkLabels = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("text")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("class", "linkLabel")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkLabel" + i })
                .attr("font-size", 16)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("")

            linkLabels
                .append("textPath")
                .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#linkPath' + i })
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .text(function (d) { return d.type })

            node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            node.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("circle")
                .attr("r", 30)
                .style("fill", "whitesmoke")
                .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
                .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)

            node.selectAll("text")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("text")
                .style("class", "icon")
                .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 20)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("dy", "-1em")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name
                })
            node.append("text")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 13)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("dy", "0.5em")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.id
                })

            force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            force
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }

        function mouseEnter(event, d) {
            const selNodes = node.selectAll("circle")
            const selLink = link
            const selLinkLabel = linkLabels
            const selText = node.selectAll("text")
            const related = []
            const relatedLinks = []

            related.push(d)
            force.force('link').links().forEach((link) => {
                if (link.source === d || link.target === d) {
                    relatedLinks.push(link)
                    if (related.indexOf(link.source) === -1) { related.push(link.source) }
                    if (related.indexOf(link.target) === -1) { related.push(link.target) }
                }
            })
            selNodes.classed('faded', true)
            selNodes.filter((dNodes) => related.indexOf(dNodes) > -1)
                .classed('highlight', true)
            selLink.classed('faded', true)
            selLink.filter((dLink) => dLink.source === d || dLink.target === d)
                .classed('highlight', true)
            selLinkLabel.classed('faded', true)
            selLinkLabel.filter((dLinkLabel) => dLinkLabel.source === d || dLinkLabel.target === d)
                .classed('highlight', true)
            selText.classed('faded', true)
            selText.filter((dText) => related.indexOf(dText) > -1)
                .classed('highlight', true)
            
            force.alphaTarget(0.0001).restart()
        }

        function mouseLeave(event, d) {
            const selNodes = node.selectAll("circle")
            const selLink = link
            const selLinkLabel = linkLabels
            const selText = node.selectAll("text")

            selNodes.classed('faded', false)
            selNodes.classed('highlight', false)
            selLink.classed('faded', false)
            selLink.classed('highlight', false)
            selLinkLabel.classed('faded', false)
            selLinkLabel.classed('highlight', false)
            selText.classed('faded', false)
            selText.classed('highlight', false)
            
            force.restart()
        }

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            // update node positions
            node
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });

            linkPaths.attr('d', function (d) {
                return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
            });

            linkLabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
                if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
                    var bbox = this.getBBox();

                    rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                    ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                    return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
                }
                else {
                    return 'rotate(0)';
                }
            });

        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;

            PosX = d.x
            PosY = d.y
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues you can look at to get the fade/ highlight running:

---

Firstly, notice the `force` method mutates the `links` array in `graph`.

E.g your first link starts like this:

```
{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1,
  "type": "need"
}
```

But becomes this:

```
{
  "index": 0
  "source": {
    "id": 0
    "index": 0
    "name": "beer"
    "vx": 0.036971029563580046
    "vy": 0.04369386654517388
    "x": 394.1514674087123
    "y": 220.18458726626062
  },
  "target": {
    "id": 1
    "index": 1
    "name": "water"
    "vx": -0.021212609689083086
    "vy": 0.01105162589441528
    "x": 568.911363724937
    "y": 177.07991527420614
  },
  "type": "need"
}
```

So you need a recursive function but you will get empty arrays if you refer to `link.source` - instead you need to refer to `link.source.id` because that's how `force` has updated your graph object per the above example.

Here's a fairly verbose, recursive function that returns all the nodes and links for a given node id that are linked by links of a give `type`:

```
function nodesByTypeAfterForce(nodeId, sieved, type) {

  // get the links for the node per the type
  const newLinks = graph.links
    .filter(link => link.type === type && link.source.id === nodeId);

  // get the linked nodes to nodeId from the links 
  const newNodes = newLinks
    .map(link => graph.nodes.find(newNode => newNode.id === link.target.id));

  // concatenate new nodes and links
  (sieved.links = sieved.links || []).push(...newLinks);
  (sieved.nodes = sieved.nodes || []).push(...newNodes);

  // recursively visit linked nodes until exhausted options
  newNodes.forEach(node => nodesByTypeAfterForce(node.id, sieved, type));

  // return indices relevant nodes and links
  return {
    nodes: sieved.nodes.map(node => node.index),
    links: sieved.links.map(link => link.index)
  };
}
```

Note the function returns an array of `index` which is an attribute `force` assigns to each node and link. This makes the filtering for the fade/ highlight more explicit later on.

---

Now, in `mouseEnter` you can start off by calling this function to return just the nodes linked together by links of a certain `type` and passing `d` to initialise the search:

```
function mouseEnter(event, d) {

  // sub graph for the hovered node
  const sieved = nodesByTypeAfterForce(d.id, {nodes: [d]}, "need");
  //...
}
```

That replaces the construction of the `related` array which in your OP is not with respect to `type`. Whilst that could be easily fixed, the other issue in your current `mouseEnter` is that you have these lines.

```
selLink
  .filter((dLink) => dLink.source === d || dLink.target === d)
```

and

```
selLinkLabel
  .filter((dLinkLabel) => dLinkLabel.source === d || dLinkLabel.target === d)
  .classed('highlight', true)
```

This is causing the highlight of the link (and link label) to any linked nodes instead of just the ones linked by a `type` (e.g. `need`).

So, I propose you replace with this code block (I moved all the lines to fade everything into their own section):

```
// only highlight from sieved
node.selectAll("circle")
  .filter(node => sieved.nodes.indexOf(node.index) > -1)
  .classed('highlight', true)
link
  .filter(link => sieved.links.indexOf(link.index) > -1)
  .classed('highlight', true)
linkLabels
  .filter(link => sieved.links.indexOf(link.index) > -1)
  .classed('highlight', true)
node.selectAll("text")
  .filter(node => sieved.nodes.indexOf(node.index) > -1)
  .classed('highlight', true)
```

Which is now only highlighting nodes and links per the `index` returned from the `nodeByTypeAfterForce` function above.

---

The working example is below where `nodeByTypeAfterForce` is just dropped in after the definition of `graph` and the only other edits are in `mouseEnter`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background: #e6e7ee;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .faded {
        opacity: 0.1;
        transition: 0.3s opacity;
    }

    .highlight {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <svg id="svg"></svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "beer",
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "water",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "hop",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "malt",
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "yeast",
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "car",
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "wheels",
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "tires",
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": "rubber",
                },
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "name": "radio",
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 1,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 2,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 3,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 0,
                    "target": 4,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 10,
                    "target": 11,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 11,
                    "target": 12,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 12,
                    "target": 13,
                    "type": "need"
                },
                {
                    "source": 10,
                    "target": 14,
                    "type": "use"
                }

            ]
        }


        function nodesByTypeAfterForce(nodeId, sieved, type) {

          // get the links for the node per the type
          const newLinks = graph.links
            .filter(link => link.type === type && link.source.id === nodeId);

          // get the linked nodes to nodeId from the links 
          const newNodes = newLinks
            .map(link => graph.nodes.find(newNode => newNode.id === link.target.id));

          // concatenate new nodes and links
          (sieved.links = sieved.links || []).push(...newLinks);
          (sieved.nodes = sieved.nodes || []).push(...newNodes);

          // recursively visit linked nodes until exhausted options
          newNodes.forEach(node => nodesByTypeAfterForce(node.id, sieved, type));

          // return indices relevant nodes and links
          return {
            nodes: sieved.nodes.map(node => node.index),
            links: sieved.links.map(link => link.index)
          };
        }

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
            .attr("height", window.innerHeight)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // append markers to svg
        svg.append("defs").append("marker")
            .attr("id", "arrowhead")
            .attr("viewBox", "-0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 8)
            .attr("refY", 0)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .attr("markerWidth", 50)
            .attr("markerHeight", 50)
            .attr("xoverflow", "visible")
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", "M 0,-1 L 2 ,0 L 0,1")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .style("stroke", "none")

        var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", linksContainer)
        var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", nodesContainer)

        var force = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id
            }).distance(80))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2))
            .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(90))

        initialize()

        function initialize() {

            link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
                .style("display", "block")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", 1)

            linkPaths = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("path")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("class", "linkPath")
                .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
                .attr("stroke-opacity", 1)
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkPath" + i })
                .style("display", "block")

            linkLabels = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("text")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("class", "linkLabel")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkLabel" + i })
                .attr("font-size", 16)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("")

            linkLabels
                .append("textPath")
                .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#linkPath' + i })
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .text(function (d) { return d.type })

            node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            node.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("circle")
                .attr("r", 30)
                .style("fill", "whitesmoke")
                .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
                .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)

            node.selectAll("text")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("text")
                .style("class", "icon")
                .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 20)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("dy", "-1em")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name
                })
            node.append("text")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 13)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("dy", "0.5em")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.id
                })

            force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            force
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }

        function mouseEnter(event, d) {

            // sub graph for the hovered node
            const sieved = nodesByTypeAfterForce(d.id, {nodes: [d]}, "need");
            
            // fade everything
            node.selectAll("circle").classed('faded', true)
            node.selectAll("circle").classed('highlight', false)
            link.classed('faded', true)
            link.classed('highlight', false)
            linkLabels.classed('faded', true)
            linkLabels.classed('highlight', false)
            node.selectAll("text").classed('faded', true)
            node.selectAll("text").classed('highlight', false)
            
            // only highlight from sieved
            node.selectAll("circle")
              .filter(node => sieved.nodes.indexOf(node.index) > -1)
              .classed('highlight', true)
            link
              .filter(link => sieved.links.indexOf(link.index) > -1)
              .classed('highlight', true)
            linkLabels
              .filter(link => sieved.links.indexOf(link.index) > -1)
              .classed('highlight', true)
            node.selectAll("text")
              .filter(node => sieved.nodes.indexOf(node.index) > -1)
              .classed('highlight', true)
            
            force.alphaTarget(0.0001).restart()
        }

        function mouseLeave(event, d) {
            const selNodes = node.selectAll("circle")
            const selLink = link
            const selLinkLabel = linkLabels
            const selText = node.selectAll("text")

            selNodes.classed('faded', false)
            selNodes.classed('highlight', false)
            selLink.classed('faded', false)
            selLink.classed('highlight', false)
            selLinkLabel.classed('faded', false)
            selLinkLabel.classed('highlight', false)
            selText.classed('faded', false)
            selText.classed('highlight', false)
            
            force.restart()
        }

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            // update node positions
            node
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });

            linkPaths.attr('d', function (d) {
                return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
            });

            linkLabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
                if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
                    var bbox = this.getBBox();

                    rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                    ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                    return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
                }
                else {
                    return 'rotate(0)';
                }
            });

        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;

            PosX = d.x
            PosY = d.y
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You will run into a stack overflow if you define a link like this e.g. with "Yeast":

```
"links": [ // Yeast need yeast ??
  {
    "source": 4,
    "target": 4,
    "type": "need"
  },
  ...
]
```

So some extra logic would be required in `nodesByTypeAfterForce` to accommodate self-referencing links.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion (`getNeedChain` calls itself until done):

```
const getNeedChain = id => {
  const links = graph.links.filter(l => l.source === id && l.type === "need");
  const nodes = links.map(l => graph.nodes.find(n => n.id === l.target));
  const linked = nodes.reduce((c, n) => [...c, ...getNeedChain(n.id)], []);
  return [...nodes, ...linked];
}

console.log('Beer needs: ', getNeedChain(0));  // Returns 4 nodes
console.log('Car needs: ', getNeedChain(10));  // Returns 3 nodes
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I get the idea but could you please explain the code further. I do not understand if [...nodes, ...linked} are placeholders or actual code. Since I only want to perform those action during a mouseEnter() I assume this belongs there.

Comment: `nodes` are directly linked "needs" of a given node. `linked` are recursively found "needs" of the `nodes`. Thus, the joint array of two arrays `[...nodes, ...linked]` has the full list of "needs" for a given node.You can use array `concat` as well but it's less elegant (IMAO)

Comment: I tried to implement your idea but received empty arrays. Obvously I do not understand the implementation. Do you mind to assist me with?